# How to define a function which takes any number of parameters in scheme?

Tags: function, parameters, numbers, scheme

I want to define a function which takes a number of parameters which can be changed.

I  thought that my function should take one parameter as a list and then parse that but it didn't work or I wrote it wrong.

Calling of the function will vary as belov.I thought to define the function as

```
(define function (lambda(list)(...
```

then work on list but it didn't work out.Thanks

```
(function param1 '(2 3) '(3 1))

(function param1 '(2 3) '(3 2) '(1 5))
```

Comment: In which language do you want to do that ?

Comment: In Scheme language,I use drRacket and I am new in Scheme.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax for this, where all parameters will be automatically put into a list:

```
(define function
  (lambda lst ; no parentheses!
    lst))
```

or the equivalent

```
define (function . lst) ; mind the dot!
    lst)
```

then

```
(function '(2 3) '(3 1))
=> '((2 3) (3 1))
(function '(2 3) '(3 2) '(1 5))
=> '((2 3) (3 2) (1 5))
```

Inside your function (in my example I simply return the list) you can then process the list with higher-order functions (`map`, `filter`, ...) or dissect them with `first`, `second`, or similar.

You can also have a number of fixed parameters first, and then the variable part, example:

```
(define (function p1 p2 p3 . lst) ; p1-3 are fixed
    (values p1 p2 p3 lst))

(function 'this 'is 'fixed '(2 3) '(3 1))
=> 
'this
'is
'fixed
'((2 3) (3 1))
```